# Why is the hyperbolic plane homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, whilst the 2-sphere isn't?

Tags: general-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology, noneuclidean-geometry

Geometrically speaking, one might consider the hyperbolic space $H^2$ and the sphere $S^2$ as manifolds which deviate from the euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ in exactly opposite ways – $H^2$ having constant negative curvature, $S^2$ constant positive curvature.

However, $S^2$ also has a quite different *topology* from $\mathbb{R}^2$, whereas $H^2$ is homeomorphic to it. What's the reason for this qualitative difference, or rather for the topological non-difference between $H^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: The reason $H^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic is because one can right down a formula for the homeomorphism and verify the definition of homeomorphism using that formula. The reason $H^2$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2$ is because the first is not compact, the second is compact, and compactness is a homeomorphism invariant. There's not much else to say.

Comment: The pseudosphere is a model of hyperbolic space with constant curvature, which is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$.  I think there may be less going on here than you suspect.

Comment: @LeeMosher that's just kicking the stone down the road: why is $S^2$ compact but $H^2$ not then?

Comment: I didn't kick it very far, I just tapped it with my little toe. Apply the Heine-Borel Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the length of a perimeter of a circle in all the geometries. It is $2\pi\sin(r) = \Theta(1)$ in spherical geometry, $2\pi r = \Theta(r)$  in Euclidean geometry, and $2\pi\sinh(r) = \Theta(e^r)$ in hyperbolic geometry.

There is a significant difference between all the three situations -- in Euclidean perimeters and areas grow polynomially with the radius, while in hyperbolic geometry they grow exponentially. In spherical geometry everything is bounded. However, topology cares only about whether it is bounded or not, so Euclidean and hyperbolic are the same topologically.

Not sure whether it helps other people, but I like to imagine the discrete version of this:  build a graph out of equiltateral triangles, where $k$ meet in a vertex. For $k<6$ you get a finite spherical graph (icosahedron for $k=5$), for $k=6$ you get an infinite triangular grid on the plane, and for $k>6$ you get a tesselation of a hyperbolic plane. Curvature corresponds to $6-k$. Again, the number of vertices in distance $d$ is bounded for $k<6$, polynomial for $k=6$, and exponential for $k>6$.

Answer (score 6):

We have a "catastrophe" at $\kappa=0$. Increasing $\kappa$ ever so slightly leads to a compact space, while decreasing $\kappa$ ever so slightly keeps the topologic type of the plane. Its a similar thing with $y=x^3+\epsilon x$: When $\epsilon\geq0$ we have just one zero, when $\epsilon<0$ there are three of them.

Such phenomena are abundant in mathematics. They may occur whenever we have a "situation with a parameter".